# Access to Web-application inside Docker

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, docker

Here are what I have:

- the physical computer (1)
- i have installed the virtual machine on this computer (virtual box, bridged networking, ubuntu server, ip=192.168.1.80)
- inside this virtual machine I have deployed the docker container (ip=172.17.0.2, gitlab (web application))

I have access to gitlab (172.17.0.2) from virtual machine(192.168.1.80).  But I need access to it from physical computer (1).  How can I get it ?

Do I need to install nginx on virtual machine (192.168.1.80) and config it to route incode requests to docker container ?  Or something else ?

Thanks

**Update:**

Nginx with option proxy_pass are working fine, but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the way you're doing it now, using nginx as a proxy, you could also set the firewall to redirect an outside port on the VM to the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the docker container's exposed port to the hosts port.  But, then you've mapped a container to port 80 and what happens when you want another container web app on the host.  I prefer reverse proxy setup with nginx, there's even a container for it.